# Javascript: How to call a function at the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, function, target

In my index page, I have a button with the "onclick='function' attribute.
But when i click on this button it writes the new text with the function made on new page.

The text what was showed before, is now disappears.
Can i give a button a target attribute, so the text that is writing by the function does not show in a new page.

Comment: Place a `return false;` in your function or `onclick="function();return false;`"

Comment: Helps if you give actual code and not an explanation of said code.

Comment: Buttons don't redirect to new pages by default. Also, the JavaScript code contained in one page cannot affect a page loaded afterwards. Please provide more information about your problem, especially code. As it is, your question is far from being clear.

Answer (score 3):

Cancel the standard click handling of the hyperlink with `return false`:

```
<a href="myFunction(); return false;">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return false;` in your function.

```
function test(){
    alert('hai');
    return false;
}

<a href="#" onclick="return test();">test</a>
```

Comment: This is probably cleaner than the other answer, simply because you can add `onclick="test()"` to as many elements as you want without having to think about adding `return false` every time too. Not sure if you could actually call using `onclick` clean though!

Comment: This won't work though. You also have to return the return value from the inline event handlder: `onclick="return test()"`